# Relations between minors of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

**motivation:** I'm looking at the Segre embedding, given by (for this example) $\mathbb{P}(U) \times \mathbb{P}(V) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(U\otimes V)$, $([u],[v]) \mapsto [u\otimes v]$. This is an embedding. If $\dim U = m+1$ and $\dim V = n+1$ then we are embedding a $m + n$ dimension variety into a $mn + m + n$ dimension variety. Looking at the polynomial equations satisfied by all points in the image, I see that all the 2x2 minors of $[u\otimes v]$ vanish. So I guess that the ideal $I(S)$ is generated by the determinants of these minors. However, there are going to be $$\frac{mn+n^2m+m^2n +n^2m^2}{4}$$ minors.

**question:** What (if any) are the  polynomial relations between the determinants of the 2x2 minors of a matrix?

Comment: A quick google is telling me that these are Plucker relations http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43965/how-many-minors-i-need-to-check-to-conclude-all-minors-will-vanish

Comment: Ok, I've answered my own question I suppose. Nothing to see here...

Comment: There is a really nice discussion of this Shaferavich--I would suggest looking at that :)

Comment: Just to clear up some terminology: a "minor" is the determinant of a square submatrix, so its no need to say take "determinants of the minors".

Comment: Dear @AnonymousCoward, why not post what you've discovered as an answer? It may well prove useful to a future visitor to the site.